# How to optimize this math formula in javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, iteration, code-complexity

I've a large sequence of container and each container have a different capacity so for each container I make some calc, basically I start with

```
for (i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
...
}
```

Now, for each container I've to find how many iteration I've, so in my case I've this

```
var disponibility = 100;
var loss = 0;
var base = 1;
var target = 2.26;
var max = 1000;
var verymax = 1000000;
var bbreak = false;
var t = 0;

while (loss <= disponibility) {
  teoric = ((loss + (base*(target-1)))/(target-1)) + 1e-6;

  teoric = Math.max(1,teoric);

  if (teoric > max || (teoric*(target-1) > verymax)) {
    bbreak = true;
    break;
  }

  loss = loss+parseInt(teoric);
  t++;
}
```

The problem became with a large number of containers and with large disponibility, all became slow and complex.

Any idea about how to reduce the complexity to find t in a short time?

The goal is to obtain the t value

Comment: Do the calculations depend on all the containers or are the independent?

Comment: Where is `t` initialised? Where is `teoric` declared? What does `bbreak` do?

Comment: I initialized t, my mistake! bbreak is only a break for certain condition, after the loop if bbreak is true I make others actions :D

Comment: the calculation depends on container, only because I populate an external array, so every items on it "i" are correlated, so my option1[i] is correlated to option4[i] and so on

Comment: Are these variables constants or parameters based on *container*?  I can suggest some minor naive improvements if they are constants.  For example, if **teoric** less than **max** then can **teoric*(target-1)** ever be greater than **verymax** (assuming target is constant of 2.26)?

Comment: the constants change for every container, every container have their own constants.